# Python GDAL open dataset in PostGIS with quotations

Tags: python, postgis, gdal, postgresql, sql

Error trying to use gdal to open a dataset in PostGIS with the following code:

```
ds = gdal.Open("PG: dbname=nyc host=localhost user=postgres password=mypassword port=5432 mode=2 schema=public column=rast table=mytable where='collected_date > 2014-04-04 07:00:00'", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
```

The log file in PostGIS shows:

> 2016-04-18 21:09:36 MYT ERROR:  syntax error at or near "07" at
>   character 336
>
> 2016-04-18 21:09:36 MYT STATEMENT:  select srid, nbband, ST_XMin(geom)
>   as xmin, ST_XMax(geom) as xmax, ST_YMin(geom) as ymin, ST_YMax(geom)
>   as ymax, scale_x, scale_y from (select ST_SRID(rast) srid,
>   ST_Extent(rast::geometry) geom, max(ST_NumBands(rast)) nbband,
>   avg(ST_ScaleX(rast)) scale_x, avg(ST_ScaleY(rast)) scale_y from
>   public.cea where **collected_date > 2014-04-04 07:00:00** group by
>   ST_SRID(rast)) foo

Apparently there is a syntax error in the date condition (in bold), where it needs to be enclosed with quotations. But I can't seem to be able to insert the quotations at all as they are always removed when the string is parsed.

I guess we can replace the date with mktime function instead, but I'll looking for a solution that can be extended to string datatype as well.